# Prevent title space changing when animating with descender letters

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I am trying to animate some monthly data using `gganimate`. The plots are working great, except that the presence of descenders (letters that go below the baseline, i.e. g, j, p, q, and y) changes the amount of space that the title takes up. This, in turn, moves the baseline of the title just a bit, which detracts from the animation. That is, the title noticably "jumps" up a bit when there is a descender in the title.

An example:

```
myDF <-
  data.frame(
    Date = seq(as.Date("2015-01-15")
               , as.Date("2015-12-15")
               , "1 month")
    , x = 1:12
    , y = 1:12
  )

myDF$frame <-
  factor(format(myDF$Date, "%Y-%b")
         , levels = paste0("2015-", month.abb))

toAnimate <-
  ggplot(
    myDF
    , aes(x = x
          , y = y
          , frame = frame)
  ) +
  geom_point() +
  theme_gray()

gganimate::gganimate(toAnimate)
```

[image]

Using an older version of `gganimate` the issue was more obvious(and did not require the inclusion of the year to demonstrate), as it moved the plot instead of the title:

```
gganimate::gg_animate(toAnimate)
```

[image]

I can "fix" the issue by using all caps (which has no descenders), but I don't particularly like the look of all caps for this (particularly as part of larger titles for the actual use case). I could also prepend the frame title with something that already has a descender e.g. `ggtitle("Timeperiod: ")` though I'd rather not add irrelevant text just to workaround this issue (adding "Timeperiod: " is what I have gone with for now though).

I've looked through the help on `theme` in `ggplot2`, but I am not seeing anything that looks like it would address this issue.

Comment: Have you tried updating *gganimate*?  The most current version has replace function `gg_animate` with `gganimate`.  I can't reproduce the descender issue with the newer version.

Comment: Thanks @aosmith. I just updated, and the problem is now far more subtle (to the point of potentially not being an issue). However, the update appears to now cause the baseline of the title to move (which is better than the plot area changing, but still not ideal). The issue is less subtle when there is a lead in to the month in the title, so I have adjusted the plot slightly (included the year) to make it easier to see.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the title only gets the height of the text, and not the font's height, when reserving space for the title.

So you could instead use `geom_text` to place a title somewhere in the plot. For example, if I do:

```
ggplot(myDF, aes(x=x,y=y, label=frame)) +
   geom_point()+theme_gray() + 
   geom_text(x=2.5,y=5,aes(label=frame),adj=0)
```

(just as a ggplot, not animated yet...) I can see all the 2015's exactly overlapping, and the descenders of the month names are clearly there, and the text baseline is constant.

So if you can put your title in a handy space on the plot, you could use that, and use `title_frame=FALSE` in your `gganimate`.

I'd also consider a bug/enhancement report to `ggplot2`. If you make the title large enough it actually stomps on the plot:

```
ggplot(myDF, aes(x=x,y=y)) +geom_point()+theme(plot.title=element_text(size=rel(10),debug=TRUE)) + labs(title="y")
```

[image]

Comment: This is a solid workaround, and a great help. In practice, the plot I am making is complicated enough (facets, factors, etc.) that using `geom_text` as a title workaround is less than ideal. It is very interesting to see that the "fault" (?) may lie in `ggplot2`'s handling of space reservation. However, I am not sure this use case is sufficient to justify reorganizing that. Upvoted, but I am going to leave as un-accepted for a little while to see if an answer that addresses the issue comes up (I doubt it, as I think your explanation precludes that).

Comment: If there was some way of adding an invisible "y" to the title, that might work... I couldn't see any `element_text` options to fix the height either.