# How to keep plot dimensions equal when ggtitle contains letters q,y,p,g,j

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have noticed that in ggplot when you add a title containing lowercase letters q,y,p,g,j the dimensions of the plot gets modified.

[image: full view comparison]

zoom

[image: zoomed-in comparison]

*the red lines have been added manually

As you can see, the height of the plot gets smaller when I add one of the above letters to the title

How can I keep the height constant between several plots with different titles?

Code used to produce the two plots:

```
# plot 1
ggplot(mpg, aes(factor(cyl), hwy)) + 
  geom_point(size=4) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  ggtitle("main")

# plot 2
ggplot(mpg, aes(factor(cyl), hwy)) + 
  geom_point(size=4) + 
  theme_bw() +
  ggtitle("pmain")
```

Comment: May be relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43098650/prevent-title-space-changing-when-animating-with-descender-letters Though note that question hasn't been satisfactorily resolved either.

Comment: Can you provide the code and data used to produce these plots?

Comment: for the first plot
`ggplot(mpg, aes(factor(cyl), hwy)) + geom_point(size=4) + theme_bw() + ggtitle("main")`
 
and for the second plot
`ggplot(mpg, aes(factor(cyl), hwy)) + geom_point(size=4) + theme_bw() + ggtitle("pmain")`

Comment: A non-code workaround, but how about standardizing all plot titles to start with something like "Figure 1..." / "Figure 2..." / etc? That will force the title to accommodate both ascender & descender letters. (You can of course use theme to turn the title white, turn off clipping, & add custom annotations in the title area, but I think the non-code way is simpler & more robust in this case.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could add a phantom lowercase letter, but that requires your text to be converted into a plotmath expression which may have some downsides, fontwise

```
.st <- function(s){
  bquote(phantom("tp")*.(s))
}

# plot 1
p1 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(factor(cyl), hwy)) + 
  geom_point(size=4) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  ggtitle(.st("main"))

# plot 2
p2 <- ggplot(mpg, aes(factor(cyl), hwy)) + 
  geom_point(size=4) + 
  theme_bw() +
  ggtitle(.st("pmain"))

grid.arrange(p1,p2,ncol=2)
```

[image]

Comment: obviously one could place the phantom characters on the right to keep the text left-justified