# Fix Plot Size in ggplot2 relative to plot title

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm using ggplot2 to create some figures with titles, but finding that when titles have a descender (e.g., lowercase p, q, g, y) the actual size of the plot shrinks slightly to accommodate the larger space needed by the title.

Are there ways within normal ggplot functionality to fix the plot size so that figures are in 100% consistent position regardless of title?

Here's some quick sample code that shows the issue; folks might need to run code locally to clearly see the differences in the images.

```
 library(ggplot2)
 # No letters with descenders in title
 ggplot(data=mtcars,aes(x=disp,y=mpg)) + 
    geom_point() + ggtitle("Scatter Plot")
```

[image: No Descender]

```
# Title has a descender (lowercase 'p')
ggplot(data=mtcars,aes(x=disp,y=mpg)) + 
    geom_point() + ggtitle("Scatter plot")
```

[image: Descender]

Comment: I recall this has been asked before, in the context of [animation with different titles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43098650/prevent-title-space-changing-when-animating-with-descender-letters) (where the descender problem was even more obvious). I don't think ggplot2 addressed this directly, but you may wish to check out the workaround / comments in that thread. I usually cheat by making sure there's a descender letter in every title.

Answer (score 2):

you can set the relevant height in the gtable,

```
library(ggplot2)

p1 <- ggplot() + ggtitle("a")
p2 <- ggplot() + ggtitle("a\nb")

gl <- lapply(list(p1,p2), ggplotGrob)
th <- do.call(grid::unit.pmax, lapply(gl, function(g) g$heights[3]))
gl <- lapply(gl, function(g) {g$heights[3] <- th; g})
gridExtra::grid.arrange(grobs = gl, nrow=1)
```

[image]

Edit: here's how to edit one plot for simplicity

```
g = ggplotGrob(qplot(1,1) + ggtitle('title'))
g$heights[3] = grid::unit(3,"line")
grid.draw(g)
```

Comment: Ah, this is neat! There is way more parameters than I realized going on here... Is there a more direct way to specify this? Or do you mind showing how you'd specifically set the height for a single table for simplicity sake?

Comment: So... throwing a letter with a descender in the title still squeezes the plot. (changing 'title' to 'title q' or similar, you'll see that)

Comment: Just found this issue w/ no fix on GIthub: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/2288